# How to Implement Drag-Resizable Row Heights in a DataGrid (MUI)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a MUI application that utilizes a DataGrid to display tabular data. I've successfully implemented the functionality to resize column widths by dragging, but I'm struggling to find a suitable approach for allowing users to dynamically adjust row heights by dragging.

I've searched extensively, but most resources focus on column resizing or general row height adjustments. What I specifically need is a solution that allows users to drag and adjust the height of individual rows within the DataGrid.

Has anyone successfully implemented this feature in a Mui DataGrid? If so, could you please share your approach or provide some guidance on how to achieve drag-resizable row heights? Any code snippets, examples, or recommended libraries would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Also added a video url to see what i want

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23978885?key=104f4c2d529dfeb117b579a9a6b9cf9b